# Finding very large jumps in data

Tags: python, numpy, outliers

I need to find very large jumps only so that I can find clusters and later the noise as well. The sample data is as under:

```
0.000000
0.000500
0.001500
0.003000
0.005500
0.008700
0.012400
0.000000
0.000500
0.001500
0.003000
0.005500
0.008700
0.012400
0.000000
0.000500
0.001500
0.003000
0.005500
0.008700
0.012400
0.000000
0.000500
0.001500
0.003000
0.005500
0.008700
0.012400
0.000000
0.000500
0.001500
0.003000
0.005500
0.008700
0.012400
0.000000
0.000500
0.001500
0.003000
0.005500
0.008700
0.012400
0.012400
```

I need to do this in python, but any generic algorithm would be welcome as well.

I have already tried

1. Finding distance between each consecutive pair of points.
2. Find the ratio of consecutive distances.
3. Find the closeness of the consecutive ratios.

The problem I face is when I use the compare function `numpy.allclose()` , its approximation factor is static and for varying degree of jumps, it stops working and gives false positives and false negatives.

Some of the graphs for data visualization. The bottom graph in each is the total number of points.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you give some examples of cases you consider FP/FN? Some plots might help us to understand your data.

Answer (score 7):

First, you should visualise your problem to get a better understanding what's going on:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = (0.000000, 0.000500, 0.001500, 0.003000, 0.005500, 0.008700,
        0.012400, 0.000000, 0.000500, 0.001500, 0.003000, 0.005500,
        0.008700, 0.012400, 0.000000, 0.000500, 0.001500, 0.003000,
        0.005500, 0.008700, 0.012400, 0.000000, 0.000500, 0.001500,
        0.003000, 0.005500, 0.008700, 0.012400, 0.000000, 0.000500,
        0.001500, 0.003000, 0.005500, 0.008700, 0.012400, 0.000000,
        0.000500, 0.001500, 0.003000, 0.005500, 0.008700, 0.012400, 
        0.012400)
plt.scatter(range(len(data)), data)
```

[image: Scatter plot of data]

Second, you need to implement a step detection, which is well described on the wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_detection

Choose a method you think would fit best and play around with it.

**UPDATE**

Just a thought: if all your data look similar to your example, you could also simply try to make a sawtooth wave (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave) least square fit (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) to find the "jumps". This could be a starting point for further analysis.

Comment: I have already visualized the data, and every block of data follows a different profile, except that there is repetition of pattern in the data itself, the way you must have seen)

Comment: Alright, then you're now on the right path. You have to understand that it's your job to solve this problem. It requires work but if you follow my advice you'll eventually figure it out, I'm sure. You can't expect people doing the work for you…

Comment: Also note that there is no exact solution to your problem. You'll have to figure out the right strategy and parameter ranges which all depend highly on your dataset. No volunteer would sit down and spend hours/days to do it for you for free...

Answer (score 2):

Your approach works if you compute the closeness "manually" this way:

```py
import numpy as np
data = np.array([0.000000, 0.000500, 0.001500, 0.003000, 0.005500, 0.008700,
        0.012400, 0.000000, 0.000500, 0.001500, 0.003000, 0.005500,
        0.008700, 0.012400, 0.000000, 0.000500, 0.001500, 0.003000,
        0.005500, 0.008700, 0.012400, 0.000000, 0.000500, 0.001500,
        0.003000, 0.005500, 0.008700, 0.012400, 0.000000, 0.000500,
        0.001500, 0.003000, 0.005500, 0.008700, 0.012400, 0.000000,
        0.000500, 0.001500, 0.003000, 0.005500, 0.008700, 0.012400, 
        0.012400])
steps = data[1:] - data[:-1]
ratios = 1. * steps[1:] / steps[:-1]
jumps = ratios[1:] - ratios[:-1]
largest_jumps = np.max(jumps)
print largest_jumps

>> 3.31102877071
```

Comment: This I've done already, but as you must have observed in the graphs i provided, there are multiple jumps (and I do not know how many in advance), and I need to find all of them.

Comment: what do you want to do exactly with the jumps? get the max of them? sort them?

Comment: I,d use the jumps to segregate the data into smaller clusters and then apply standard clustering and anomaly detection algorithms. (because without that DBSCAN is giving poor results, refer to the images above)

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing fancy, but you could try it. Using forward, backward differences you can detect single outliers. It will fail in complex cases if multiple outliers lay together tho, but for simple cases it might work:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(20)    
# Synthetic data
sample = np.random.randn(20)
# Synthetic noise
sample[np.random.randint(0, 20, 5)] += np.random.randn(5) * 100

plot(x, sample, 'o')
```

[image]

Get forward and backward derivatives (their absolute value as we care about magnitude of differences not direction):

```
d1 = np.r_[0, np.abs(sample[1:] - sample[:-1])]
d2 = np.r_[np.abs(sample[1:] - sample[:-1]), 0]
```

Mask the inliers with a threshold (they have at least another node close):

```
mask = (d1 < 5) | (d2 < 5)
```

Show results:

```
plot(x[mask], samples[mask], 'o')
```

The hardcoded `5` for the example could be replaced by the `mean` or the `median` + `std` or something.

Again, is not something fancy, as @septi pointed out, there is a lot of theory in outlier detection and no easy approach solves every problem. For more information you can check [`density based outlier deetection`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_outlier_factor), which I think is suitable for your problem.

[image]